# Confusion about signed Radon measures, Continuous functions and duals

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, duality-theorems

I am studying Radon measures and the duals spaces. There are many slightly different versions of the associated spaces and I am trying to wrap my head around which is related to which space of continuous functions.

Let $X \cong Y$ mean that X is isometric to Y, and denote with $X^\ast$ the dual space of $X$. Consider over $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ the spaces

- $ba(\Omega)$, space of bounded finitely additive measures
- $rba(\Omega)$, space of regular bounded finitely additive measures
- $\mathcal{M}(\Omega)$ or $rca(\Omega)$, space of regular bounded countably additive measures
- $C_b(\Omega)$, space of bounded continuous funtions
- $C_c(\Omega)$, space of compactly supported continuous funtions
- $C_0(\Omega)$, space of continuous funtions that vanish on the boundary of $\Omega$

Am I right in saying that

1. $C_0(\Omega)\subseteq C_c(\Omega) \subseteq C_b(\Omega)$
2. $rba(\Omega)\cong C_b(\Omega)^\ast$ for arbitrary $\Omega$
3. $rca(\Omega)\cong C_c(\Omega)^\ast$ for compact $\Omega$
4. $rca(\Omega)\cong C_0(\Omega)^\ast$ for arbitrary $\Omega$

Thanks for helping me clarify matters.

Comment: In 1), you should swap $C_c$ and $C_0$. Also, I don't think that the dual of $C_c$ is a normed space, so talking about isometric isomorphisms is a bit misleading. Finally, $\Omega$ should probably be open (or something) for $C_c(\Omega)$ to be reasonable (e.g., to vanish on the boundary).

Comment: Also, $C_c^\ast$ will contain countably additive measures that are *not bounded*.